# In which situations would I want to call -rollback in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I try to grok this method. Is that only useful when I'm dealing with undo/redo operations? Or can I use that in general, when I have changed my object graph after saving it and then decide that that was a bad idea? So -rollback would go back to the last saved state of my object graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"So -rollback would go back to the last saved state of my object graph?"

That's exactly it - "restores updated objects to their last committed values"

When you are performing multiple, or complex changes or alterations you may want to work on the managed objects directly but still allow a user a final chance to hit the "Cancel" button. That's one time you would use it.

Comment: So the difference between -rollback and -reset is, that my object graph will still be there, where as -reset would throw it away completely?

Comment: As I understand it, yes, that's the difference